# Can't make one to many database work in flask

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, one-to-many

I am trying to get the Team_names_id column to be filled with the correct id number but it only fills with null. Please help I've been stuck on this for hours. I am very much a beginner, but I haven't found anything that solves my problem no matter what I do the column stays empty. The database will even acknowledge the foreign key but it will not populate the column.

```
from distutils.command.sdist import sdist
from enum import unique
from turtle import back
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS']= True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'sdafwer3rw93ur9wu0er339d'

class Forms(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'forms'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    names = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable = False)
    emails = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)
    team_name_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team_names.id'))
    #theteamnames = db.relationship('Team_names', backref = 'forms')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Forms %r>' % self.id
    
    def __init__(self, names, emails):
        self.names = names
        self.emails = emails
        
class Team_names(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'team_names'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    team_name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique = True)
    formss = db.relationship('Forms', backref = 'team_names', lazy='dynamic')
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Team_names %r>' % self.id

    def __init__(self, team_name):
        self.team_name = team_name
        
@app.route('/new', methods=['POST','GET'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        givennames = request.form['names']
        givenemails = request.form['emails']
        giventeamnames = request.form['team_names']
        
        adding1 = Team_names(team_name = giventeamnames)
        adding = Forms(names = givennames, emails = givenemails) 

        try: 
            db.session.add(adding)
            db.session.add(adding1)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('thankyou.html')
        except: 
            return 'There was an error adding your team please try again or team name was not unique'
    else:
        return render_template('new.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, you are missing the link that tells the `Forms` object which `Team_names` to associate it with. You would do this by populating the backref, `team_names`, in the 'Forms' table. Simply modify your line where you declare `adding`, to this:

```py
adding = Forms(names = givennames, emails = givenemails, team_names=adding1)
```

Note you will also need to modify your `__init__` function in your 'Forms' table to accept this `team_names` parameter.